# Hazelcast get all by partion key

Tags: hazelcast, oracle-coherence

i use hazelcast. There is an IMap with PartitionAware keys.
Is it possible to usw these key to receive all values of an partition?

With respect to this example:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/13b180910abec2cf3605149cb905e2a6fcf5ca39/distributed-map/data-locality/src/main/java/DataLocalityMember.java

When i like to receive all orders of customer X:

```
orderMap.values(Predicates.equal("customerId", 10))
```

Is there a posibility to receive all values of matching partition to speed the query up?

Is there an equvalent to Orcale Coherence:

```
com.tangosol.util.filter.KeyAssociatedFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Partition Predicates in Hazelcast? I guess it is what you are asking: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/manual/html-single/#filtering-with-partition-predicate